# C++ Issue with Stream Operators

Tags: c++, struct, iostream, cout, cin

I'm very new to Cpp and am having some issues declaring input streams. I keep getting an error, "error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> new_contact.Person::Name', in addition to a whole slew of other things that all relate back to misuse of the >> operator it looks like. Here is the code, as well as the structure for each of the structs being used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::map;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

typedef struct {
    string Name;
    map<string,int> Number;
} Person;

void addContact(vector<Person> Contacts) {
    Person new_contact;
    char ans;
    string name;
    cout << "What is the name of your new contact (first name)? " << endl;
    cin >> new_contact.Name;
    cout << "Do you want to enter a number for your contact? " << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    while (ans == 'y') {
        cout << "What type of number are you entering? " << endl; //ex CELL, FAX, HOME, WORK, etc.
        cin >> name;
        cout << "What is the number of your contact? " << endl;
        cin >> new_contact.Number[name];
        cout << "do you want to enter another number? " << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    }
    Contacts.push_back(new_contact);
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong as I do not see any glaring issues when comparing what I have with previous errors people have run into (most people experiencing this issue seem to put the endl command at the end of the cin stream, however, I have not done this). Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Now, I am stuck with an infinite loop while trying to recheck the 'ans' variable. The function simply infinitely loops through alternating "Do you want to enter another nummber?" and "What type of number are you entering?" with no input from me.

Comment: You will probably discover at some point that your function has no effect, since it operates only on a local variable and causes no side effects (apart from consuming input). You will also discover that your persons cannot have spaces in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> new_contact.Name` requires an overload of `operator>>` for `vector<char>`, which doesn't exist.

The simplest fix is to change the type of the `Name` member:

```
string Name;
```

Comment: Awesome; that worked 100%. Why exactly does that not work? I understand the overload of operator>>, but does vector use the >> operator for anything? Sorry; very new to cpp! Also, will I run into that same issue trying to import from stream into a map?

Comment: @Eric: It's simply that nobody has defined an `operator>>` for `vector<char>`. There isn't one, and there probably aren't any sensible semantics you could give to such an operator that would be worthwhile.

Comment: thanks for your help, I appreciate it! As a side note, do you know how I can clear ans so that I can fill it with new data? It looks like as of now, there is no way for me to change its contents and I run into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Eric: There are many, *many* more issues with your code. I probably know the answer to all to them, but your C++ teacher or book know them even better.

Comment: I'm trying to sort through things. We just switched from C to C++ after a month of C (my first programming language) and then skipped the first 8 chapters of the book in C++.